# How to stub an async database call with sinon

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to unit test the `getAll` method on this class:

```
module.exports = class BookController {
  static async getAll() {
    return await Book.query()
      .eager('reviews');
  }
};
```

Book is a Objection model.

How I'd like to test it is I want to fake the response from `Book.query().eager()` with my own data, since I can never verify what's in the database. For it to be a true unit test, should I just be testing that the `Book.query()` method is called?  Or should I be testing that the returned data since that's the contract of the `getAll()` method? I'm really unsure how I should be stubbing this out.

Answer (score 5):

With Sinon > 2.x, you can call `.resolves()` on your stub. I would do something like

```
var stub = sinon.stub(BookController, 'getAll');
stub.resolves({response:"ok"});
var bc = new BookController();
bc.getAll.then(function(data){
    expect(data.response).to.equal("ok");
    done();
},function(err){
    done("should NEVER get here");
});
```

Comment: ohhh snap...thats for stubbing out your `getAll()` function :D. Process is the same/similar for Book.query(). Sorry for the confusion bud!